# CMake CPPLINT coloured output

Tags: cmake, lint, cpplint

Is there any way to colour the cpplint output when setting

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT "cpplint")
```

in the cmake file?

Comment: `to colour the cpplint output` To what color? Cyan?

Comment: yes, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to color any output, you have to communicate that intention to the thing that displays it. For **displaying** the output of commands, typically a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) is used, nowadays in the form of terminal emulator.

**If** your terminal supports [ANSI color escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), you could just [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) `cpplint` process and output a color code before and after it is run. On a *unix environment you could create an executable file named `mycpplint` with the content along:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\E[36m' ; cpplint "$@" ; printf '\E[0m'
```

and then add that executable file location to `PATH` and do `set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT "mycpplint")`.

Comment: Thanks this works! is there any option to include the script into the cmakefile? something like (not working, throws a No such file or directory): 

set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT "printf '\\033\[0\;34m' \; cpplint \"$@\" \; printf '\\033\[0m'")

or setting a command or a variable to encapsulate the call in the cmakefile. We are going to compile in different computers, and it would be great to have it in the cmakefile itself.